# Trying to open a PR from the command line with bash

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to open the PR link in github with bash from the command line.

I have this so far:

```
stripped=$(sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//' <<< $git_branch)
repo=$(basename `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)
alias pull='open https://github.com/comapny/$repo/compare/$stripped?expand=1'
```

There are two issues with this

1) I get these errors whenever i open terminal, because my home directory is not a repo

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
usage: basename string [suffix]
       basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]
```

2)  When I `cd` into a repo i need to do `source ~/.bash_profile` in order to get the `pull` command to work. but after i do that it works perfectly

Thoughts on how I eliminate issues 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a function for this:

```
pull() {
  stripped=$(sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//' <<< "$git_branch")
  repo=$(basename "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)")
  open "https://github.com/comapny/$repo/compare/$stripped?expand=1"
}
```

Aliases is more for stuff like adding colors to `ls` and line numbers to grep, etc...

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep -n'
```

Also remember quotes or you will get unexpected word splitting and globing.